# Saving entity in many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

(3am here, so bear with me!)

This is EF6. I have many-to-many relationship between entities `Procedures` and `Points`. I create a new `Procedure` object named `P` and add one of the existing `Point` objects to its `Points` collection. I then send `P` to EF for saving:

```
context.Procedures.Add(P);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunately this tries to INSERT the `Point` object too into the database, which obviously fails with duplicate primary key error.

Among serveral other things, I checked the value of `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and to my astonishment, it contains 21 entries instead of just 2. Upon further investigation, it looks like EF is creating entries for the recursive `Procedure > Point > Procedure` relation. How can I fix this problem?

### Edit

(4am now, :))

I have *made it to work* with the following code:

```
var Temp = P.Points.ToArray();
P.Points.Clear();

foreach (var t in Temp)
  P.Points.Add(context.Points.Find(t.Id));

context.Procedures.Add(P);
```

Is there really the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Your `Point` model object was obtained from database (EF)?

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho: Yes

Comment: How you make the relationship mapping?

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. I have imported my model from SQL Server into EF (Database First), which resulted in the creation of `Procedure` and `Point` entities (among others) and a many-to-many relation between them.

Comment: Do you use foreign keys or navigation properties ? If you unset the navigation property Point and set your foreign key, if I remember well, it should work.

Comment: @romain-aga: See my edit. About navigation property, `Points` is a collection type on my `Procedure` object `P` and only takes a `Point` object. How can I add a foreign key to it?

Comment: It's when you update your edmx, you can check if you want to remove the foreign keys or not. Be sure to keep them and then, you should be able to use the foreign key field in your entity.